# Perform segue is not having any impact

Tags: ios, sqlite, segue, viewcontroller

I have following code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
    indexPathRow = indexPath.row;  
    NSLog(@"indexPathRow.%d", indexPathRow);  
    mylist.recordIdToEdit = [[myIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPathR NSLog(@"Item selected..%d", safetyInventoryList.recordIdToEdit);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailsViewController" sender:nil];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
  if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailsViewController"])
    {
       DetailsViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
       int itemIdToFetch = myList.recordIdToEdit;
       [detailedList fetchDetails:itemIdToFetch];
       destViewController.name = detailedList.itemName;
       destViewController.itemId = itemIdToFetch;
    }
}
```

my segue identifier is correct and perform segue works fine if i dont have any processing in my preparefor segue! Also, i tried to move the fetching data from DB to detailed view controller instead of prepareforsegue, in its viewdidload. that also has no effect. the details view controller is not shown and no error is thrown. Program halts there
!

Comment: what the problem u faced..

Comment: Problem faced is its not showing up the next VC. its stuck at previous VC. No segue is performed though no error thrown!

Comment: what is this "mylist.recordIdToEdit" array or str

Comment: its int - the integer value

Comment: then do one thing remove this method "prepareForSegue" and add the value in **NSUserDefaults** it is easy way na.

Comment: other wise try this method allocate the secondviewcontroller in didselectrowatindexpath and add the value to  second view controller string

Answer (score 0):

Remove line

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailsViewController" sender:nil];
```

from didSelectRowAtIndexPath and try.

Make sure your segue has identifier name DetailsViewController you can check this by selecting segue and select Attribute Inspector StoryBoard segue identifier name.

Comment: if I remove it where should i perform segue? And I have already mentioend my identifier is proper

Comment: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

Comment: This method identifies your view controller change

Comment: Just remove [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailsViewController" sender:nil];from - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath and try running your app .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65203/discussion-between-nagarjun-and-smitha).

Comment: If you are using UITableViewCell select ur cell+ctrl and draw segue .

Answer (score 0):

I think You should try to fetch data from DB to detailed view controller but in different thread,

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

dispatch_async(queue, ^{

  });
 });
```

Hope it will solve your issue.